# Problema con "tr" en filtro por fecha con datable y datapicker

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Tengo esta datatable

```
minDateFilter = "";
maxDateFilter = "";
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(function (oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
    if (typeof aData._date == "undefined") {
        aData._date = new Date(aData[0]).getTime();
    }

    if (minDateFilter && !isNaN(minDateFilter)) {
        if (aData._date < minDateFilter) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    if (maxDateFilter && !isNaN(maxDateFilter)) {
        if (aData._date > maxDateFilter) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Date_search").val("");
});

var table = $("#tabla").DataTable({
    deferRender: true,
    autoWidth: false,
    search: {
        regex: true,
        caseInsensitive: false
    }
});

$("#Date_search").daterangepicker(
    {
        locale: {
            format: "YYYY-MM-DD",
            separator: " to ",
            applyLabel: "Apply",
            cancelLabel: "Cancel",
            fromLabel: "From",
            toLabel: "To",
            customRangeLabel: "Custom",
            weekLabel: "W",
            daysOfWeek: ["Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa"],
            monthNames: [
                "January",
                "February",
                "March",
                "April",
                "May",
                "June",
                "July",
                "August",
                "September",
                "October",
                "November",
                "December"
            ],
            firstDay: 1
        },
        opens: "center"
    },
    function (start, end, label) {
        maxDateFilter = end;
        minDateFilter = start;
        table.draw();
    }
);
```

y esta es la tabla:

```
Date: <input id="Date_search" type="text" placeholder="Buscar por Fecha" /><br>

<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="tabla">
        <thead>
            <tr>

                <td>Id Sitio</td>



                <td>Nombre del Sitio</td>


                <td>OT / FG</td>



                <td>Quien Retira</td>



                <td>Empresa</td>



                <td>Celular</td>



                <td>Fecha Entrega</td>


                <td>Operador Entrega</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)

            {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IdSitio)
                </td>



                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NombreSitio)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OTFG)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QuienRetira)
                </td>



                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Empresa)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Celular)
                </td>



                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Fecha)
                </td>



                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OperadorEntrega)
                </td>
            </tr>

            }

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Resulta el datapicker no me filtra a menos que a cada encabezado  y a cada body le ponga un tr, lo que yo hice fue colocar un tr para el encabezado y un tr para el body pero no me funciona el filtro por con el datapicker.

He seguido la documentación de DataTable para el filtrado de un rango de fechas y no encuentro lo que me está fallando.

He buscado en stackoverflow y en internet y no encuentro ninguna solución a mi problema.

¿Alguna idea para hacer que funcione?

Gracias